# How can I return a Future object with Spring without writing concurrency logic?

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, java-ee-6

How can I return a `java.util.concurrent.Future` object with a Receipt object and only use the `@javax.ejb.Asynchronous` annotation?

And do I need any extra configuration to let Spring handle ejb annotations?

I don't want to write any concurrency logic myself.

Here's my attempt that doesn't work:

```
@Asynchronous
public Future<Receipt> execute(Job job) {
    Receipt receipt = timeConsumingWork(job);
    return receipt;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as your configuration is correct, all you need to do is to return a new `AsyncResult` object with the receipt as input parameter.

```
@Asynchronous
public Future<Receipt> execute(Job job) {
    Receipt receipt = timeConsumingWork(job);
    return new AsyncResult<Receipt>(receipt);
}
```

Spring handles both `@Async` and `@Asynchronous` with the `<task:annotation-driven />` element.

Comment: I don't see import java.util.concurrent.AsyncResult - what would I need to import to use this?

Comment: javax.ejb.AsyncResult<V> is part of Java EE. It's not in the java.util.concurrent package. An alternative is to use the compatible org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncResult<V> from SpringSource. It can be downloaded from here: http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/